# pm2 --env NODE_ENV is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

`console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` always gives "production"

My process.json:

`{
    "apps" : [
        {
            "script"      : "server-local.js",
            "watch"       : ["views"],
            "ignore_watch": ["node_modules"],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development",
            },
            "env_production" : {
                "NODE_ENV": "production"
            }
        }
    ]
}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your command?